# complex data() attachment to HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was just glancing through the code in modal.js and I came across the following line, with which I have difficulty, below is the line, I am having a difficulty with :

`if (!data) $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))`

You can find this line on github too: [line 289](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L298).

Now, obviously, the above line is attaching data() to an HTML element, my problem is I am finding it difficult to visualize how it is doing this:

Specifically my problem is with the 1st parameter passed into the data() method, now the Jquery doc's clearly says that the 1st parameter is the `key` and the 2nd param is the `value`, that said if the below line executes:

`if (!data) $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))`

What will the constructed data on the HTML element look like?

```
bs.modal : {
       this.options             = options
    this.$body               = $(document.body)
    this.$element            = $(element)
    this.$dialog             = this.$element.find('.modal-dialog')
    this.$backdrop           = null
    this.isShown             = null
    this.originalBodyPad     = null
    this.scrollbarWidth      = 0
    this.ignoreBackdropClick = false
}
```

something like the above? I am really confused about what the end result would look like, can somebody really clarify , the usage of `bs.modal` as the 1st param?

I did do this to check what the end product looked like:

```
  1    console.log($this.data('bs.modal'));
  2    if (!data) $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
  3    console.log($this.data('bs.modal'));
```

and I get the following result:

```
line:1       undefined 
line:3       Object { options: Object, $body: Object, $element: Object, isShown: null, $backdrop: null, scrollbarWidth: 0 }
```

but I don't see `bs.modal` anywhere.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code breaks down like this:

```
if (!data)
```

This condition will hit if the `data` variable is `null`, `undefined`, or an empty string.

```
$this.data('bs.modal', ...)
```

This is the setter for jQuerys `data()` method.

```
data = new Modal(this, options)
```

This is setting the `data` variable to equal a new `Modal` object. Because it is inside the setter of the `data()` variable it is also setting the `bs.modal` data value as well. It is the equivalent of this code:

```
var x = a = 'foo';
console.log(x); // = 'foo'
console.log(a); // = 'foo'
```

The reason you don't see `bs.modal` in the console output of your final example is because it is the key of the object and you are displaying the value.